# My ViewModel knows about the View, how do I fix this?

Tags: c#, events, mvvm, command, viewmodel

I think the code is self-explanatory.

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Deleting">
        <MVVMLight:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Deleting, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                  PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </Interactivity:EventTrigger>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I have my own custom control with a delete event and want to bind it to a command in the ViewModel.

But in the view model, I have now either

```
public void OnDeleting(EventArgs args)
{
    var e = args as MapDeletingEventArgs;

    if (e == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("args");

    Database.Delete(e.Maps);
    Database.Commit();
}
```

or worse

```
public void OnDeleting(MapDeletingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("args");

    Database.Delete(args.Maps);
    Database.Commit();
}
```

And I know how bad it is to have view logic in the ViewModel. I can think of no better way, does anyone advice? I use the framework MVVMLight as you can see maybe.

Comment: From the code you've shown, there's no "view logic" in the ViewModel. Your view model doesn't "know" about the view, it just knows it has a method called OnDeleting that is a handler for a command when it is executed. I'm not sure what you're worried about. Are you getting errors? Is the command firing?

Comment: Yes everythink works great, im worring about if my programming style is right. I want to learn clean coding, and my feeling is that passing view eventargs to the viewmodel is not so clean. Is it?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with an `ICommand` implementation that takes a `Map` instance as it's command parameter:

```
//WARNING: all code typed in SO window
public class DeleteMapsCommand : ICommand
{
    private Database _db;

    public DeleteMapsCommand(Database db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public void CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        //only allow delete if the parameter passed in is a valid Map
        return (parameter is Map);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var map = parameter as Map;
        if (map == null) return;

        _db.Delete(map);
        _db.Commit();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged; //ignore this for now
}
```

You then create a public property in your view model to expose an instance of the command

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel() {
        //get the Database reference from somewhere?
        this.DeleteMapCommand = new DeleteMapsCommand(this.Database); 
    }

    public ICommand DeleteMapCommand { get; private set; }
}
```

Finally you need to bind your action to the command property **and** bind the command property to the map to be deleted.  You haven't really given me enough of your XAML to state how this should be done in your case, but you could do something like the below with a `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListOfMaps" ItemsSource="{Binding AllTheMaps}" />
<Button Command="{Binding DeleteMapCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ListOfMaps}">Delete Selected Map</Button>
```

**Update**

To attach the command to the event you can use an attached property:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static IComparable GetDeleteMapCommand(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (IComparable)obj.GetValue(DeleteMapCommandProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDeleteMapCommand(DependencyObject obj, IComparable value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(DeleteMapCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DeleteMapCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DeleteMapCommand", typeof(IComparable), typeof(Helper), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnDeleteMapCommandChanged));

    private static void OnDeleteMapCommandChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //when we attach the command, grab a reference to the control
        var mapControl = sender as MapControl;
        if (mapControl == null) return;

        //and the command
        var command = GetDeleteMapCommand(sender);
        if (command == null) return;

        //then hook up the event handler
        mapControl.Deleting += (o,e) =>
        {
            if (command.CanExecute(e.Maps))
                command.Execute(e.Maps);
        };
    }
}
```

You then need to bind the command like this:

```
<MapControl local:Helper.DeleteMapCommand="{Binding DeleteMapCommand}" />
```

Now your view model has no reference to the view-specific types.

Comment: But this doesn't look like what OP is asking for. @slopsucker needs a command to fire when his control's "Deleting" event fires, which is what he or she is already doing. The concern seems to be that there is view logic, of which I don't see any (no references to specific controls or their properties), in the view model.

Comment: @Ryan true, I hadn't taken the event handler into account

Comment: Right, my problem is the specific MapDeletingEventArgs which are only in this a control (Control.Map.dll) that makes me stuzig if that was not already an implementation of view in the view model

Comment: Just to expand on Steve's edit, the OP is using MVVM Light which already has a EventToCommand object, so he could use that instead of an attached property.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer I think the problem with OP's use of EventToCommand is that he wants some intermediate "device" to strip the Maps collection from the event args and pass that to the view model. An attached property or behavior can be that "device". That's assuming I understand what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hand your EventArgs off to your viewmodel, you could try using a Behavior (this is similar to Steve Greatrex's solution, but uses the Blend SDK'a behavior instead):

Here is an example I use in one of my applications.

First, here's my custom behavior base class:

```
/// <summary>
/// "Better" Behavior base class which allows for safe unsubscribing. The default Behavior class does not always call <see cref="Behavior.OnDetaching"/>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The dependency object this behavior should be attached to</typeparam> 
public abstract class ZBehaviorBase<T> : Behavior<T> where T : FrameworkElement
{
    private bool _isClean = true;

    /// <summary>
    /// Called after the behavior is attached to an AssociatedObject.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Override this to hook up functionality to the AssociatedObject.</remarks>
    protected sealed override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.Unloaded += OnAssociatedObjectUnloaded;
        _isClean = false;     
        ValidateRequiredProperties();     
        Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the behavior is being detached from its AssociatedObject, but before it has actually occurred.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Override this to unhook functionality from the AssociatedObject.</remarks>
    protected sealed override void OnDetaching()
    {
        CleanUp();     
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the required properties. This method is called when the object is attached, but before
    /// the <see cref="Initialize"/> is invoked.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual void ValidateRequiredProperties()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the behavior. This method is called instead of the <see cref="OnAttached"/> which is sealed
    /// to protect the additional behavior.
    /// </summary>
    protected abstract void Initialize();        

    /// <summary>
    /// Uninitializes the behavior. This method is called when <see cref="OnDetaching"/> is called, or when the
    /// <see cref="AttachedControl"/> is unloaded.
    /// <para />
    /// If dependency properties are used, it is very important to use <see cref="ClearValue"/> to clear the value
    /// of the dependency properties in this method.
    /// </summary>
    protected abstract void Uninitialize();

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the <see cref="AssociatedObject"/> is unloaded.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void OnAssociatedObjectUnloaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CleanUp();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Actually cleans up the behavior because <see cref="OnDetaching"/> is not always called.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This is based on the blog post: http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2011/04/safe-event-detachment-pattern-for.html.
    /// </remarks>
    private void CleanUp()
    {
        if (_isClean)
        {
            return;
        }

        _isClean = true;

        if (AssociatedObject != null)
        {
            AssociatedObject.Unloaded -= OnAssociatedObjectUnloaded;
        }

        Uninitialize();
    }
}
```

Now, my concrete implementation used to attach a command to the TextBlock's "click" event

```
public class TextBlockClickCommandBehavior : ZBehaviorBase<TextBlock>
{
    public ICommand ClickCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ClickCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ClickCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClickCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ClickCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(TextBlockClickCommandBehavior));

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonUp);
    }

    protected override void Uninitialize()
    {
        if (this.AssociatedObject != null)
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonUp -= new MouseButtonEventHandler(AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonUp);
        }
    }

    void AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // if you want to pass a command param to CanExecute, need to add another dependency property to bind to
        if (ClickCommand != null && ClickCommand.CanExecute(null))
        {
            ClickCommand.Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
<!--Make the TextBlock for "Item" clickable to display the item search window-->
<TextBlock x:Name="itemTextBlock" Text="Item:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" FontWeight="Bold">
    <e:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ZViewModels:TextBlockClickCommandBehavior ClickCommand="{Binding Path=ItemSearchCommand}"/>
    </e:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBlock>
```

Now, in your case, instead of passing NULL to the command's execute method, you'd want to pass your arguments' Maps collection